# MongoDB schema design/join in monogo db

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I'm new to MongoDB with strong background in SQL and don't know what's the ideal way to design the following scenario:

I have set of machines that sends pings to main machine, and I need to know which machines sent a ping in the last 10 minutes.

I have 2 collections:

1. `pings` - a very big collection, each machine send a ping about every 10 minutes.
2. `machines` - pretty small collection, about less 1000 machines

and I need to query for the "Alive" machines, i.e all the machines that sent ping in the last 10 minutes.

Currently my schema looks like:

```
pings = {
    _id       - ObjectID
    machineID - ObjectID
    pingTime  - ISODate
}

machines = {
    _id       - ObjectID
    name      - String
    type      - string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data modelling in MongoDB works differently than with SQL. With SQL, you identify your entities, their properties and their relations and then you bang your head against the wall to get your JOINs right to answer the questions that arise from your use cases.

With MongoDB and – with varying extent – the other NoSQL databases, data modelling works differently: You identify the questions that arise from your use cases *first*, and model your data *accordingly* so that the questions can get answered in the most efficient way.

Let us assume you have a web application in which you see a list of machines, and clicking on the individual machine you want to get the machine details. So we have a known machine we want to inspect. As simple as this may sound, it is important here. Assuming your list is generated from your `machines` model, you already have all the information at hand for generating the machine details view:

```
db.pings.find({machineID:givenmachine["_id"]})
```

For the use case you described, I would change the `ping` data model a bit:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectID(),
  machine: "host.example.com",
  pingTime: new ISODate()
}
```

Reason: Contrary to popular belief having redundancy is not bad thing per se. *Unneccesary* redundancy is. But your use case validates it, as it makes your query *much* more efficient:

```
t = new Date()
t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() - 10);
db.pings.distinct("machine",{pingTime:{$gte:t}})
```

Have an index on pingTime, it will be lightning fast, only one collection involved. And even if you changed a machines name, this should be a rather rare use case compared to checking the up-state(?) of those machines.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about redundancy(it's called embed in mongo isn't?) but what if I want also bunch of properties about the machine? so I'll end with a big ping document... what I don't know if mongo suits for my use case or that I should stay with RDBMS...

Comment: @Michael Hence you should get all your questions straight *first*, before modelling. But again: You have an efficient query for the hosts that sent a ping, now you can do a `db.machines.find({name:{$in:resultset}})` for your limited subset. Even better, say you want a details page, you only need to do a simple query like `db.machines.find({name:nameOfMachineYouWantTheDetailsFor})`.

Comment: Hm.. I understand what you saying, it's little wierd to think like that after all the normalization in SQL...
Do you know a "migration" tutorial from sql to mongo? maybe with scenarios that implement in SQL and how it implement in Mongo?

Comment: @Michael Aside from that: Embedding is the procedure where you embed valid documents inside another. In this case, we only have redundant data ;) You might want to read [a blog post of mine](https://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb.html) regarding embedding and - almost as important - over embedding.

Comment: LOL, I really think there is no problem with RDBMS, but currently I have project that maybe mongo will suit it better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157723/discussion-between-michael-and-markus-w-mahlberg).